# 32-bit block addresses in ext4 inode struct

Tags: ext4

[In the Linux kernel source](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/cbb104f91dfec8ae5bc67ff6dc67b824330a0919/fs/ext4/ext4.h#L749), the block numbers in an on-disk inode struct are 32-bit. Why? Surely Linux can support more than 2^32 blocks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The interpretation of the array `inode.i_block` [is different in Ext4](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#The_Contents_of_inode.i_block) compared to previous on-disk filesystem formats. In Ext4, when the inode has the `EXT4_EXTENT_FL` set in `i_flags` this array stores the root of the extent tree and up to four extent descriptors (`struct ext4_extent` or `struct ext4_extent_idx`). You will notice that in the extent descriptor there are 48 bits for the block address. For older on-disk formats, e.g. Ext3, the maximum number of block does indeed fit in 32 bits.

See [Ext4 data structures and algorithms](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/ext4/index.html), section [4.2 The Contents of inode.i_block](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/ext4/dynamic.html#the-contents-of-inode-i-block).

Comment: Why isn't it declared as a union?

Comment: @extremeaxe5: I have no idea.